# How to limit to 1 friend result using facebook graph without FQL?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

Today I am successfully retrieving the list of my friends, however I would like to search for 1 specific friend (by user id "number")

dynamic friends = client.Get("me?fields=friends.fields(id,name,gender,picture.type(normal))", new { limit = "5000", offset = "0" });

How can I accomplish that in the case above?

thanks

Comment: How is this related to MVC?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the friend's ID, then just use `/{friend_id}`. Otherwise this could be tough because since v2.0 of the Graph API the endpoint `/me/friends` is only returning the friends of the user which also use the app.